# Send scheduled emails in Android - Alternatives

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I need to schedule the automatic sending of emails for the future. This can be anything from a few minutes to a few days or weeks into the future.

From the research that I've done, I think this would be possible using `AlarmManager` but I've read in another post ([Android alarmmanager not being very reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828324/android-alarmmanager-not-being-very-reliable)) that it's not very reliable and the events could potentially get cancelled.

What other possible approaches are there to accomplish such tasks?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've read in another post... that it's not very reliable and the events could potentially get cancelled.

It's fairly reliable, as reliable as you are going to get. Events can get canceled (e.g., because the user force-stops your app), because it's the user's phone, not yours, and they get to control their phone, not you.

> What other possible approaches are there to accomplish such tasks?

Use `AlarmManager`, please. Anything else will be less reliable and waste RAM and battery life.

Comment: Just going to leave this here, maybe it will help someone. I needed my  events to still be active when the phone was shut down, so besides adding them to AlarmManager, I also saved them to a database and registered a service to listen to a RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED. That way, when the device is rebooted and comes back on, the service can go to the database and reconstruct those alarm events that got cancelled on shut down. Also remember to register the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission in your Android manifest file.